# Residue of $\frac{1}{z\cos z}$ at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the residue of the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{z\cos z}$ at $z=\infty$.

We have, $$Res(f,\infty)=Res \left[z^2f(1/z),z=0\right].$$
Now, $\displaystyle z^2f(1/z)=\frac{z^3}{\cos(1/z)}=\frac{z^3}{1-[1/z^22!-1/z^44!+\cdots]}=z^3\left[1+(1/z^22!-1/z^44!+\cdots)+(1/z^22!-1/z^44!+\cdots)^2+\cdots\right].$

So $Res(f,\infty)=\text{ coefficient of $1/z$}=-1/4!$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: You didn't add the term $(1/(z^22!))^2$ to the coefficient of $1/z^4$

Comment: The residue at $\infty $ equals $\text{Res}\left[\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right),0\right]$

Comment: Considering that $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z\cos z}$, how do we define the residue of $f$ at $\infty$?

Comment: @Zarrax, I am pointing out that $f$ cannot be expanded in Laurent series around $\infty$.